# Change Default SegmentedControl Divider color

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, uisegmentedcontrol

how can i change this divider color in swift?
[image]

I tried this:

```swift
setDividerImage(UIColor.white.image(CGSize(width: 0.1, height: 0.1)),
                forLeftSegmentState: .normal,
                rightSegmentState: .normal,
                barMetrics: .default)

extension UIColor {
    func image(_ size: CGSize = CGSize(width: 1, height: 1)) -> UIImage {
        return UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: size).image { rendererContext in
            self.setFill()
            rendererContext.fill(CGRect(origin: .zero, size: size))
        }
    }
}
```

But the issue is, that it takes the whole height of the segmentedControl regardless which divider height i set. If i also use the approach above it also creates a divider next to the selected segment which the apple defaults one doesn't have and i don't want also.

[image]

Comment: No sir , customise height of divider is not possible ... you need to create custom component for that ...

Comment: isn't it possible to just change the color of the divider instead of setting an image color @jawadAli

Comment: I didnot get you

Comment: I mean is it possible to change the color of the segment divider instead of setting an image that is actually a color.